# Dynamically switching XSLT stylesheets in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, xhtml

The short version: Is it possible to switch to alternate XSL stylesheets in the browser, a la [CSS stylesheet switching](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/)?

The long version:

I've always admired the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/); it excellently showcases the power and flexibility of stylesheets.  However, it also shines a light on one of the great weaknesses of CSS: a quick View Source reveals a wealth of tags with no semantic value, which exist solely to give the stylesheet room to work.  (Paragraph-wrapping `<span>`s, onion-layering, the half-dozen "extraDiv"s at the bottom…)

I've been playing around with the idea of using XSLT to work around this; starting with a semantically clean XHTML file and using XSLT to inject both the CSS stylesheet and any non-semantic markup required by it.  However, there seems to be little practical value in doing so unless the XSL stylesheets can be switched in the browser in a similar manner to switching CSS stylesheets.  Otherwise, each different stylesheet will cause a cache miss and you might as well do the processing on the server side.

Browser support for the [`<?xml-stylesheet?>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/) PI seems decent, but I haven't found anyway to trigger alternate stylesheets via JavaScript or browser UI (FF, Chrome).  Has anyone else tried this?

**Edit:** Oh, and browser-specific solutions are welcome; this is just an experiment, not something I expect to use on a live site anytime soon!  ;-)

Comment: Are you wanting to switch on load, or as the result of user interaction after the page is loaded?

Comment: @Robusto — As the result of user interaction, ideally.  Just as users can choose a CSS stylesheet to apply (via JS, FF's View menu, etc.), I'm hoping to find a way for XSL stylesheets to be similarly chosen.

Answer (score 2):

At least for IE you can do the transform manually in JScript and write the contents of the transform to the document. See something like [this](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/QuickRef/node_transformNode.html).

[This](http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/3630526/JavaScript-XSLT-Support-in-Firefox) is similar for FF.

Comment: I hadn't thought about it from the angle of manual transformations.  Thanks for the links!